# I want to replace all values with another array values , both arrays are in same size

Tags: javascript

eg:

```
var Array1=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
var Array2=array(7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

after replacing `Array2` with `Array1` values
Resulting array should be

```
var Array1=array(7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Comment: ok so what is the problem.?Array1 = Array2;

Comment: I believe the problem with doing that is that now both arrays are referenced. Changing a value in Array1 will also change the same value in Array2. Even if OP doesn't mention it.

Comment: did you even try anything ? In this case there's a big chance the first thing you would have tried was actually the answer...

Answer (score 63):

#### Prior ES6 (using [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)):

```
Array1.length = 0;                  // Clear contents
Array1.push.apply(Array1, Array2);  // Append new contents
```

#### Post ES6 (using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
Array1.splice(0, Array1.length, ...Array2);
```

Comment: Huge difference between Andy and @broofa's answers.  Both correct in difference contexts. Andy creates a new Array object with the same content as the second array, with a single reference to the new object, and discards the reference to the first array object.  broofa's preserves the first array object, but changes the content to match the second array object.  So any other references to the first array object elsewhere in the code see the new values.  OP's need is unclear.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer, because it actually answers the question of replacing the whole content of the array, which in turn is reflected in all references of the array elsewhere in the code.

Comment: TBF I did write that 7 years ago. Quite a lot has changed. :) @TerryBrown

Answer (score 30):

Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
Array1 = Array2.slice(0);
```

This will take a *copy* of `Array2`, *not* make a *reference* to it, so if you make changes to `Array2` they won't be reflected in `Array1`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bo5zLs9p/)

Comment: This does not replace the actual array, but rather replaces the pointer of the variable to a new Array, which might not be desirable, like in a case where you cannot point to another location in memory because other code parts already refer to the original pointer, thus the first answer here might be preferable

Answer (score 3):

in this example, it is possible to exclude the value of an array of type CONST, and the value of an array is passed to or another.
  I had this problem.

```
fields = [1,2,3,4]

var t = fields.filter(n => {
  return n != 4;
});

// t => [1,2,3]

fields.splice(0, fields.length, ...t);

console.log(fields);//[1,2,3]
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!