# How to replace an array of objects with an array including newer objects in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures, higher-order-functions

For example: I have an array of objects like this:

```
let arrayOfObjects: [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];
```

Now I want to replace or overwrite the array above with the same array, but including different values (same keys, different values):

```
let arrayOfObjects: [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Not Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Not Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Not Started" }
];
```

How can this be done in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to replace all values with another array values , both arrays are in same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640771/i-want-to-replace-all-values-with-another-array-values-both-arrays-are-in-same)

Comment: `Object.keys(arrayOfObjects).forEach(k => arrayOfObjects[k] = arrayOfObjects2[k])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JS

```js
let oneArray = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];
let twoArray = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Not Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Not Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Not Started" }
];

let newArray = Object.assign([], oneArray, twoArray);
console.log(newArray);
```

In TS

```js
interface Data {
  oneArray: array;
  twoArray: array;
}

function merge(data: Data) {
  return Object.assign([], data.oneArray, data.twoArray);
}

let user = {
    oneArray: [
      { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
      { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
    ],
    twoArray:  [
      { "id": 0, "name": "Not Available" },
      { "id": 1, "name": "Not Ready" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Not Started" }
  ]
};

console.log(merge(user));
```

Comment: Is this also possible with the same array (without creating the arrray twoArray)? Because the values in the oneAray change here.

Comment: @Codehan25 yes! `let oneArray = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];

let newArray = Object.assign({}, oneArray, [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Not Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Not Started" }
]);

console.log(newArray)` but ensure that two variables with the same name are not declared .

Answer (score 1):

Sure :)

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];

const newValues = ['Not Available', 'Not Ready', 'Not Started'];


newValues.forEach((value, i) => {
  arrayOfObjects.find(o => o.id === i).name = value;
});

console.log(arrayOfObjects);
```

I wouldn't recommend this though: [functional programming is awesome](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch03.html#oh-to-be-pure-again).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
  { "id": 0, "name": "Available" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "Ready" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Started" }
];

let names = ['Not Available', 'Not Ready', 'Not Started']
let result = arrayOfObjects.map((user, index) => ({ ...user, name: names[index] }))

console.log(result)
```